$R_{1}^{n}$ is not isometric to $R_{\infty}^{n}$
From the book 'a course in metric geometry' exercise 1.2.14 (b):
show $R_{1}^{n}$ is not isometric to $R_{\infty}^{n}$ for $n>2$.
I have tried to reach to any conclusion from the method Proof by contradiction but I have had no result.
what seemed useful to me was to think of $f(0) = C$ and $f(k) = 0$ then  
$max |C_i| = \Sigma |k_i|$ that's all I got.

What does this notation mean.  Is $R^n_p$ going to be $\mathbb R^n with the $\ell_p$ norm (and the metric it induces)?

@Aaron yes it is indeed $L^p$ norm and the metric it induces

Because translation is an isometry for both spaces, if there were an isometry, then there would also be one which preserves the origin.
Let $B_x(r)=\{y\mid \|x-y\|<r\}$ be an open ball in a normed space.  Let us call a point $v$ "special" if $B_0(1)\cap B_v(1)=B_{v/2}(1/2)$.  An isometry fixing $0$ must send special points to special points.  One can verify that the special points in both the spaces in the question are the corners of the unit balls.  In $R_1^n$, there are $2n$ special points.  In $R^n_{\infty}$, there are $2^n$ special points.  If $n>2$, then these quantities are different.

Thank you. How did you come up with this idea to consider such special points?

@hr1380 I figured that there was something special about the corners, then I tried to find a property expressible entirely in terms of the norm that would distinguish them.  I played around with a few other ideas about things I could express in terms of the norm before I hit on this idea.
